# How to upload image from gallery to server?

Tags: android, image-uploading

I am following [this example](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106), it is working fine but when I am trying to upload image but its not uploading and showing source file not exists..Can any one help me what is mistake in my code ? Thanks in advance

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {
 private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
 private String selectedImagePath;
TextView messageText;
Button uploadButton;
int serverResponseCode = 0;
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
String upLoadServerUri = null;
final String uploadFilePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
//final String uploadFileName = "";
private Button buttonLoadImage;
private ImageView img;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setType("image/*");
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
        }
    });
    uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

    messageText.setText(uploadFilePath+selectedImagePath);

    /************* Php script path ****************/
    upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                                }
                            });                      

                         uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + selectedImagePath);

                    }
                  }).start();        
            }
        });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
        }
    }
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


      String fileName = sourceFileUri;

      HttpURLConnection conn = null;
      DataOutputStream dos = null;  
      String lineEnd = "\r\n";
      String twoHyphens = "--";
      String boundary = "*****";
      int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
      byte[] buffer;
      int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
      File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

      if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 

           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               +uploadFilePath + "" + selectedImagePath);

           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           +uploadFilePath + "" + selectedImagePath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

      }
      else
      {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +selectedImagePath;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

       } // End else block 
     } 
  }
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Nothing is happening?

Comment: i mean it says source file not exists

Comment: @AdityaVyas debug and check whether image got selected

Comment: it? Who is saying that? Where? Well if the file does not exist you already know why 'nothing happens'.

Comment: seems your file path is incorrect. check if the file exists in the same path.. "/storage/sdcard/windows/PublicPictures/SamplePictures/service_lifecycle.png"                                                    
Also, please paste the error logs.

Comment: its not showing any error,just not uploading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont hard code the file location, use like this:

```
String uploadFilePath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/windows/PublicPictures/SamplePictures/";
```

try to check the file is exist or not like this:

```
            File file = new File(picturePath);
            if(file.exists()){
                //write your uploading functionality here.
            }else{
                //file not found please select another file.
            }
```

in your on activity result method change like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            File file = new File(picturePath);
            if (file.exists()) {
                uploadFileName=picturePath;
            }

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    }
```

and this also:

```
uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "",
                        "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });

                        uploadFile(uploadFileName);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Johnson  is my answer is helped for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading with this simple java code, you can add other stuffs like you using in your code say progress bar and other alerts. *Considering your file path is correct*, I would like to suggest uploading image code something like this:

```
    String url = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";
    String fileName = "/storage/sdcard/windows/PublicPictures/SamplePictures/service_lifecycle.png"; 
    //file to be uploaded
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    FileBody fileContent = new FiSystem.out.println("hello");
    StringBody comment = new StringBody("Filename: " + fileName);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileContent);
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

To check file path you can check printing something like file.length() and comparing it with size of original image.

Hope this helps you with your problem....!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your onActiviyresualt :

```
if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            Uri uri = resultIntent.getData();
            if (uri == null) {
                return;
            }
            File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                    this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, final Uri uri) {

                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                                 imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri))
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
        }
```

i hope it can help you

Comment: i am not using multipart now,as u said using single image uploading..can you help me with that

Comment: im not sure where is your problem :/

Comment: see here same code i have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27631360/send-parameters-using-post-method-to-httpconnection

Comment: (sorry i cant coment there !) what is your serverResponseCode ?

Comment: you want response ?did you see that code i mention?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {


 private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;  
 private String selectedImagePath="";  
 TextView messageText;  
 Button uploadButton;  
 int serverResponseCode = 0;  
 ProgressDialog dialog = null;  

 String upLoadServerUri = null;  

  /**********  File Path *************/  
 final String uploadFilePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();    
 //final String uploadFileName = "";  
  private Button buttonLoadImage;  
  private ImageView img;  
 //private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;  

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);
  // int a=getIntent().getIntExtra("image", RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

   img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

   buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
   buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {

         Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
       }
   });
   uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
   messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);



   /************* Php script path ****************/
upLoadServerUri = "http://www.androidexample.com/media/UploadToServer.php";

    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                               public void run() {
                                messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                               }
                           });                      
                     //use only selectedImagePath. because it contains whole path. no need to add /mnt/sdcard....
                        uploadFile(selectedImagePath);

                   }
                 }).start();        
           }
       });
  }


 @Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
           Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
           selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

           //Print imagepath in textview here
           messageText.setText(selectedImagePath);

           System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
           img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
       }
   }
 }


 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public String getPath(Uri uri) {
   String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
   int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }

public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


  String fileName = sourceFileUri;

     HttpURLConnection conn = null;
     DataOutputStream dos = null;  
     String lineEnd = "\r\n";
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     String boundary = "*****";
     int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
     byte[] buffer;
     int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
     File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

     if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

           dialog.dismiss(); 
           //use only selectedImagePath. because it contains whole path. no need to add /mnt/sdcard....
           Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                               + selectedImagePath);

           //use only selectedImagePath. because it contains whole path. no need to add /mnt/sdcard....
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                           + selectedImagePath);
               }
           }); 

           return 0;

     }
     else
     {
           try { 

                 // open a URL connection to the Servlet
               FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
               URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

               // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
               conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
               conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
               conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
               conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
               conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
               conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
               conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
               conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

               dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                         + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               // create a buffer of  maximum size
               bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

               bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
               buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

               // read file and write it into form...
               bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

               while (bytesRead > 0) {

                 dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                 bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                 bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                }

               // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
               dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
               dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

               // Responses from the server (code and message)
               serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
               String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

               Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " 
                       + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

               if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +selectedImagePath;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });                
               }    

               //close the streams //
               fileInputStream.close();
               dos.flush();
               dos.close();

          } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              ex.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });

              Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
          } catch (Exception e) {

              dialog.dismiss();  
              e.printStackTrace();

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                      Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", 
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              });
              Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " 
                                               + e.getMessage(), e);  
          }
          dialog.dismiss();       
          return serverResponseCode; 

      } // End else block 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileViewerActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {

                boolean resul = Utilty.checkPermissionsForCamera(permissions,ProfileViewerActivity.this);
                //    printLogMessage(" checkPermissionforcamera "+resul);

                userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                if (resul)
                    cameraIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

                boolean result = Utilty.checkPermission(ProfileViewerActivity.this);
                userChoosenTask = "Choose from Library";
                if ( result)
                    galleryIntent();
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                userChoosenTask="Cancel";
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();


}



private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

private void galleryIntent() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <19){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_FILE);
    }else
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_FILE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    printLogMessage("grantResults "+grantResults.length);
    printLogMessage("permissions "+permissions.length);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case Utilty.MY_PERMISSIONS_CAMERA:
            if (grantResults.length==2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
                if (userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo")){
                    cameraIntent();
                }}
            if (grantResults.length==1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo")){
                    cameraIntent();
                }}
            break;
        case Utilty.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                    galleryIntent();
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try{
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(ProfileViewerActivity.this,"File path is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    bitmap=getResizedBitmap(bitmap,200,200);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printLogMessage(" capture imageresult onCaptureImageResult "+destination.getAbsolutePath());
    selectedFilePath=destination.getAbsolutePath();
    multiPartPrfImageFile=new File(selectedFilePath);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    dynamicToolbarColor(bitmap);
}

private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Uri uri=data.getData();
    String image= ImagePath.getPath(ProfileViewerActivity.this,uri);
    printLogMessage("image path gallery"+image);
    bitmap= null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(ProfileViewerActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    selectedFilePath=image;
    multiPartPrfImageFile=new File(selectedFilePath);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    dynamicToolbarColor(bitmap);
}

private void printLogMessage(String Message) {
    Log.e("Profile", Message);
}

public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```